# How can I say "How many more students like biking than swimming?" in Spanish?

Tags: traducción, español-neutral

Do the following translations look right?

English:

> How many more students like biking than swimming?
>
> How many more students like apples than oranges?

Spanish:

> ¿A cuántos estudiantes más les gustan ciclismo que nadar?
>
> ¿A cuántos estudiantes más les gustan manzanas que naranjas?

Scenario:

x students like biking. y students like swimming.
Similarly for apples and oranges.

Comment: No se, pero me parece mejor si "mas" llega mas tarde, algo asi: "cuántos estudiantes les gustan ciclismo más que nadar?"

Comment: @B.ClayShannon La respuesta a esa pregunta sería x, no (x - y). Para que la respuesta sea (x - y) habría que preguntar ¿A cuántos estudiantes más les gusta el ciclismo que a los que les gusta nadar? O también: ¿Cuántos estudiantes más prefieren el ciclismo sobre los que prefieren nadar?

Comment: Ah, right, I misread it and was thinking it was "how many students like cycling more than they like swimming naked in snapping-turtle-infested waters"?

Comment: You can consider making this a more generic question on the form "How many more X like Y than Z?".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Estas formas son equivalentes:

> ¿A cuántos estudiantes más les gusta más el ciclismo que nadar?
>
> ¿A cuántos estudiantes más les gusta el ciclismo más que nadar?

y

> ¿A cuántos estudiantes más les gustan más las manzanas que las
>   naranjas?
>
> ¿A cuántos estudiantes más les gustan las manzanas más que las
>   naranjas?

The second form sounds better to me as both *más* aren't so close to each other.

Note that you need two *más*: Te first *más* <--> *more* and the second *más ... que* <--> *than*

Comment: This is the grammatically correct answer. In real life you would usually use the a form of the verb "preferir" precisely to prevent having two "más" so close to each other. For example "¿Cuántos más estudiantes prefieren el ciclismo antes que nadar?"

More examples can be found by googling for the phrase "prefieren * antes que".

Comment: Agree @SantiagoTórtora, aunque yo prefiero "preferir _X_ **a** _Y_" a "preferir _X_ **antes que** _Y_" ;)

Comment: Nótese que la pregunta no dice que les guste más una cosa que la otra, sino una *o* la otra.

Answer (score 4):

English:
How many more students like biking than swimming?

Spanish:
¿A cuántos estudiantes les gusta más el ciclismo que nadar?

English:
How many more students like apples than oranges?

Spanish:
¿A cuántos estudiantes les gusta más las manzanas que las naranjas?

Also you can use something like:

- ¿A cuántos estudiantes les gusta el ciclismo antes que nadar?
- ¿Cuántos estudiantes prefieren el ciclismo a nadar?

But these are not literal translation.